# Spring Stream router-sink won't start on CDF

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I tried to deploy the following stream: `http --port=1234 | router --script=D:\my-router.groovy` on `local-cdf-server` but `router` application won't start:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method router in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.integration.scripting.ScriptVariableGenerator' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.integration.scripting.ScriptVariableGenerator' in your configuration.
```

I tried defining variables but it didn't change anything.

I am using the `1.1.1.RELEASE` version of the `router-sink` on rabbit binder.

What am I doing wrong?

-- EDIT --

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'router' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'router' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptProcessor' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'scriptProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.rabbit.RouterSinkRabbitApplication.main(RouterSinkRabbitApplication.java:29) [classes!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [router-sink-rabbit-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [router-sink-rabbit-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [router-sink-rabbit-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [router-sink-rabbit-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'router' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'router' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptProcessor' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'scriptProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.resolveTargetBeanFromMethodWithBeanAnnotation(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:130) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor$1.doWith(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:189) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'router' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptProcessor' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'scriptProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptProcessor' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'scriptProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:380) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e55af1a0.scriptProcessor(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router-1.2.0.M1.jar!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration.router(RouterSinkConfiguration.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router-1.2.0.M1.jar!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e55af1a0.CGLIB$router$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router-1.2.0.M1.jar!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e55af1a0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$20464a46.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router-1.2.0.M1.jar!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e55af1a0.router(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router-1.2.0.M1.jar!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'scriptProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:658) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:569) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:567) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:566) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.findResource(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:58) ~[router-sink-rabbit-1.2.0.M1.jar:1.2.0.M1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1096) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.resolveURL(ClassPathResource.java:147) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:185) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.lastModified(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:166) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scripting.support.ResourceScriptSource.retrieveLastModifiedTime(ResourceScriptSource.java:118) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scripting.support.ResourceScriptSource.getScriptAsString(ResourceScriptSource.java:99) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.scripting.RefreshableResourceScriptSource.<init>(RefreshableResourceScriptSource.java:47) ~[spring-integration-scripting-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration.scriptProcessor(RouterSinkConfiguration.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router-1.2.0.M1.jar!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e55af1a0.CGLIB$scriptProcessor$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router-1.2.0.M1.jar!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e55af1a0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$20464a46.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router-1.2.0.M1.jar!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.router.sink.RouterSinkConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e55af1a0.scriptProcessor(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router-1.2.0.M1.jar!/:1.2.0.M1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing - it's a bug.

It's fixed on [master](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/router/commit/23ee585efe9b89b48e1cc0ded566d729f5fa0f31) and is available in the 1.2.0.M1 milestone.

Comment: I changed the version, but now I am getting a new exception, I made an edit. It looks like configuration is wrong?

Comment: I just tested it (1.2.0.M1 version) with the same stream, with no problems; I think you need `--script=file:D:\my-router.groovy` (add `file:`) otherwise it will look for the script on the classpath - but I don't think that's related to your issue (I got a "script not found" problem without it but the context loaded ok).